# Stuck when trying to make a PDF Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, response

I'm trying to make a PDF report, but I'm not even able to make the Hello World example work. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
    protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=abc.pdf");
            byte[] byteStream = createPDF();
            Response.BinaryWrite(byteStream);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }

    }

    private byte[] createPDF()
    {
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);

        using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, output);
            doc.Open();
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Hello World.");
            doc.Add(paragraph);
            doc.Close();
            return output.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

When I do Response.End(), I get no response. I don't know how to debug this request using browser developer tools. Can someone help me or give me any ideas?

Comment: Is the print button inside an `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: Thank you David. I found the answer on the linked answer.